# Populating a JavaFX TableView from an RxJava Observable<List<T>>

Tags: java, javafx-8, rx-java2, rx-javafx

I have an `Observable<List<T>>` that I want to display with a `TableView<T>`.

It seems as though there should be a library function in JavaFx to convert an RxJava `Observable<List<T>>` into a JavaFx `ObservableList<T>`, but if there is, I can't find it (though there's lots of support in RxJavaFx for going the other way).

Do I need to write my own `ObservableListBase<T>` implementation and my own implementation of `ListChangeListener.Change`, or is there a better way?

Should I just replace the items wholesale?

```
TableView<T> table = ...
Observable<List<T>> observable = ...

observable
  .observeOn(JavaFxScheduler.platform())
  .subscribe(updatedList -> {
    ObservableList<T> items = table.getItems();
    items.setAll(updatedList);
  });
```

Comment: Maybe [RxJavaFX](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaFX) can help you.

Comment: @DVarga RxJavaFX is where I found “lots of library support going the other way”. :(

Comment: Have you developed your own implementation? If so, maybe you could post it as an answer

Comment: @DavidRawson I went with the `.observeOn(JavaFxScheduler.platform())` / `setAll()` solution. It performs fine for a small table with no sorting, which is all I have to worry about right now. I don't know how well it would work in the general case.